# AEM6.5 handle component updates

Tags: components, migration, aem, aem-6

I have the following problem:
in our AEM6.5 project, there are some old components, that are used in many sites. Thing is, we have to update some of these components, which includes that the options in the cq_dialog change.
Since we have a lot of pages, it is no option to manually reconfigure those components on all pages.
Is there any way of "migrating" components?

If you have other ideas how to make breaking changes to components without manual reconfiguration, please post them. However, please spare me any "this is bad, don't make breaking changes" answers

Comment: ACS Commons Reports can give you a page list where those components are used, (or you can get them using SQL2, then using Groovy, bash/curl or any other scripting language, you can change the nodes with the expected values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An 'on-deploy script' can help you here.

See: https://adobe-consulting-services.github.io/acs-aem-commons/features/on-deploy-scripts/index.html for more information. Or Google around for more examples.

You can rename/remove/add nodes or properties or all sorts of things programmatically.